# Dimension(s) of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, homological-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $\rm R$ be a ring (unitary, associative, not necessarily commutative). $\rm M$ a left $\rm R$-module.

> **Question.** Which are natural ways to define a **dimension** of $M$?

There is Goldie's **uniform dimension** (number of uniform submodules needed to form an essential submodule; increasing, not additive), the **length** of $\rm M$ (the maximal length of a chain of submodules; increasing, additive) the **Krull dimension** (the deviation of the poset of submodules ordered by inclusion, increasing; is it additive??). Anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

Also global dimension,  composition length, Loewy length, and reduced Goldie dimension.

I think the last two are not defined for all rings though.

Comment: That is quite a bunch of examples. Do all these dimensions coincide for fields?

Comment: @Drike not offhand, but I would imagine so,